# Set::find() not working as expected with objects stored as pointer and comparison functor defined

Tags: c++, stl, set

If my set::find() function works as expected in some scenarios and does not work in others.

Since I am storing object pointers in my set I have defined a functor for comparison as below:

```
template<class T> struct ptr_compare
{
    bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};
```

My sample class is as below:

```
class A {
  private:
    string str;
  public:
    A(string s)
    {
        str = s;
    }
    bool operator <(const A& obj) const
    {
        return this->str.compare(obj.get_str());
    }
    
    string get_str() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};
```

If I write main() function as below then set::find() seem to work as expected:

```
int main()
{
    set<A*, ptr_compare<A>> myset;
    A* a1 = new A("sdkbf");
    A* a2 = new A("test");
    A* a3 = new A("sfj");
    
    myset.insert(a1);
    myset.insert(a2);
    myset.insert(a3);
    
    set<A*>::iterator it = myset.find(a2);
    if (it != myset.end())
    {
        cout << "found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output of above: found

Now If I change the order in which I insert elements in set then set::find() does not work as expected:

```
int main()
{
    set<A*, ptr_compare<A>> myset;
    A* a1 = new A("sdkbf");
    A* a2 = new A("test");
    A* a3 = new A("sfj");
    
    myset.insert(a1);
    myset.insert(a3);
    myset.insert(a2);
    
    set<A*>::iterator it = myset.find(a2);
    if (it != myset.end())
    {
        cout << "found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output of above: not found

Is this not right way to compare object pointers in a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with

```
bool operator <(const A& obj) const
{
    return this->str.compare(obj.get_str());
}
```

Here `compare` will return `-1` if `str` is less than `obj.get_str()` and `1` if `obj.get_str()` is less than `str`.  Both of those values get converted to `true` when returned as a bool from the function.  This is not what you want.  Instead, you can use `std::string`s `operator <` like

```
bool operator <(const A& obj) const
{
    return str < obj.str;
}
```

Comment: It works, But I still have a silly question, maybe i did not understood the concept fully, I am thinking when both strings are same then str.compare(obj.str) should return 0 which is false in both ways, shouldn't it work that way too. Something I missed to understood still

Comment: @mSatyam If they are both the same yes it will return `0` and be false.  Your issue is that if they are not equal, then compare either return `-1` or `1` and both of those value are `true`.  This means as long as your string are not equal then your `operator <` always returns `true`, which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Since when objects are not same then also we return true shouldn't set::find() return an iterator pointing to an object which is not a match rather than returning set::end().
Looks like I am missing how set::find() makes use of comparison function since I got this implementation also from a SO post.

Comment: @mSatyam You are in undefined behavior territory.  `std::set` requires that the comparator implements a strict weak ordering.  Your comparison function does not do that, so whatever result you get is what you get.

Comment: @mSatyam simply put, your original `A::operator<` implements **unequal** rather than **less** or **greater** required by `std::set`. This violates the expectations, and results in surprises.